# read class attribute in CasperJs

Tags: casperjs

I'm wondering whether its possible to get the class value of a li item, the html looks something like this:

```
<div id="cardsdeck">
    <ul id="cards">
        <li id="card-0" class="card-image card-shown" .... >
            ......
```

I'm trying to get card-show out of the li.

Comment: how to get that li" element by referencing its class name that containing spaces just like your case,  @Saad ? Let say i dont have the id" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is what you're trying to do, but to get and array of the classes that an element has, you can use:

```
document.querySelector('#card-0').className.split(' ');
```

However, if you're trying to get elements that have the `card-shown` class, then you can use:

```
document.querySelector('.card-shown');
```

---

**Edit:** better suited for your comment below:

```
casper.then(function() {
  var num = 0;
  var shown = this.evaluate(function isShown(k) {
    return document.querySelector('#cards li.card-shown').id == ('card-'+k);
  }, num);
  console.log(shown);
})
```

This will look for an element with the `card-shown` class and then check to see if the id matches `card-k`, with `k` being a number.

Comment: there are n <li> the visible card image has the card-shown in its class, im trying to check whether element k has class card-shown or not. This is what I have:
var e= this.getHTML('#cards li:nth-child(1)'); if(e.indexOf('card-active')); - so basically instead of 1 i would loop through i to assert on which card should be shown or not, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way to just grab class from the first li rather then the whole document

Comment: I updated this to work better with your comment. Hope it helps.